# How to fix 'Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8'?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, database

I have written the following code using Python

```
from sqlalchemy import Table,create_engine,String,Float,Integer,Column,MetaData 
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///college.db',echo = True)
meta = MetaData() 
Players = Table('Players',meta,
                Column('name',String),
                Column('number',Integer),
                Column('Speed',Float))
meta.create_all(engine) 
conn = engine.connect() 
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import update  
up = update(Players).where(Players.name == 'Rolnando').values(name = 'Messi') 
s = Players.select() conn.execute(s)
```

But I am getting the following exception

> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py",
>   line 509, in do_execute
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters) sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such
>   column: Players.number [SQL: 'SELECT "Players".name, "Pla
>   yers".number, "Players"."Speed" \nFROM "Players"'] (Background on this
>   error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Why am I receiving this error and how do I resolve it?

Comment: I new with stack overflow, please help me how to make question easy to look. Mine is messi!!

Comment: 3 slashes in URL on line 2?

Comment: It just a way to connect to sqlite

Comment: Could you explain for me why I have this error? - @Marichyasana